# How to open a file an display it in a TextBlock c#

Tags: c#

So im pretty much just starting out with c# and i'm just trying to get the text out of a .txt file and display it on my App. I've tried looking everywhere that I can think of but i've only found people doing this for console Apps and when I try apply the same solution to mine it will just gives errors. This is what i'm trying to use at the moment but I just keep getting the error: "cannot convert 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'" for the path after StreamReader(path). Ive tried it as an console app(changing the output code) and works fine

```
namespace FileOpenApp
{
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {
   public MainPage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void inputSubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           outputBox.Text = "Testing";
           processFile();
       }
   private void processFile()
   {
       try
       {
           string path = @"C:\Users\Fabian\Dropbox\test.txt";
           using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) //errors here
           {
               string line;
               while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
               {
                   outputBox.Text = line;
                   currentProcess.Text = "Done";
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           currentProcess.Text = "Something went wrong";
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Edit: trying to use this code I am getting the error that File does not exist in the namespace System.IO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;


namespace FileOpenApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void inputSubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                outputBox.Text = "Testing";
                processFile();
            }
        private void processFile()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Fabian\Dropbox\test.txt";
            string contents = "";
            System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path, contents);
            outputBox.Text = contents;
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried;

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Fabian\Dropbox\test.txt";
outputBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: `StreamReader` *does* have a constructor that accepts a file path: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Very strange.  I made my own program using your code, but with a path appropriate to my computer, and it works fine.  You should change your "outputBox.Text = line;" line to read "outputBox.Text += line;" so it will display all lines of the file, and put a line to clear that textbox before reading the file so multiple clicks will not keep adding the same file into the box repeatedly.  But other than that, it should work.  As I mentioned, it does work on my computer almost exactly as you posted it.

Comment: @WDS Yeah sorting out how it's displayed and what not is something I was going to sort later, just wanted it to actually work first lol. Either way, thank you, I guess that means there's something wrong with my Visual Studio install maybe? Im using 2015 and only just installed it along with my win 10 fresh install.

Comment: I am still using 2013.  I have seen some people comment that their 2015 is behaving differently with the same code than previous versions of VS did.  Hard to say if that would be the case here.

I could not replicate your "File does not exist in the namespace System.IO" exception either.  I do think there might be something wrong with your install or with 2015 in general.  At this point I would suggest trying to install 2013 if you can get it and see if that solves the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `File.ReadAllText()`, which does all of this for you and returns a string.

Comment: The original code ought to open the file - but it has a bug in that it effectively only loads the last line of text. This solution nicely avoids that bug.

Comment: Right, I did try using something along the lines of that before, after trying it again it's saying that 'File does not exist in the namespace of System.IO'  for the code `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path);` If i remove the System.IO it just says File does not exist in this context

Comment: @SLaks Errrr i'm not sure what you mean by that tbh, the code above is in a C# file along with a XAML file doing for the UI but other than that im using Visual Studio as my IDE, I selected just Blank App as my template when I started the project.

Comment: This should do it, is it possible if you can show complete code trying using SLaks solution?

Comment: @Angloos I updated the OP with the full code from SLacks solution (excl. the XAML code, but I don't think that's the issue)

Comment: Why are you using System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, contents);? You are trying to read the file and display the text right? Just use this textbox.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, i'm still getting the same error after trying your code that "File does not exist in the current context", only reason I had the System.IO on at the start is to try find it why it's not working and to get the error "File does not exist in the namespace of System.IO"

Comment: Ahhh .. Your name spaces are saying you have selected wrong Project Type when you were adding a project. You have Selected "Blank App (Universal App)" option. Are you sure thats what you want? Probably you want Windows Form or Web Page?

Comment: Well i've just been trying different things with it with no specific goal for the project, that's why I did blank App, but it should still work right?